# Como simular essa função PHP em jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array-multidimensional

A função abaixo feita no PHP vai me retornar um array onde a palavra buscada se encaixou, como posso fazer a mesma porém com jQuery?

```
$meuArrayMultidimensional = array(array("campo" => "teste"), array("campo" => "valor qualquer"), array("campo" => "teste"));
$search = "uma palavra qualquer";
$retorno = array_keys(
    array_filter(
    $meuArrayMultidimensional,
        function ($value) use ($search) {
            return (stripos($value['colunaDoArray'], $search) !== false);
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Onde ela se encaixou em outro array? em um string? Não ficou muito claro pra mim o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: Retorno vai buscar no meuArray na coluna especificada a string recebida na variavel $search, e vai adicionar as chaves onde essa string foi achada no array, transformando o $retorno em um array de chaves

Comment: https://3v4l.org/l7efb < este script dá erro

Comment: @MoshMage Se você executar a função sem criar as variáveis que fazem a mesma ser validada, ela irá dar erro mesmo, tente assim https://3v4l.org/K5YNt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o objectivo for filtrar para mais tarde ir buscar o campo, podes usar o [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) -- se for mesmo para tirar o `index`, podes usar o [`array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)

o equivalente ao `stripos` é `"string".indexOf()` sendo que nao podes bater contra `false` porque ele retorna `0` se o index encontrado estiver na posição 0 da string. podes também usar o `search` - se precisares de usar RegEx (pex `"hello world".search(/\sworld/i)`)

Para iterar sobre um objecto, podes faze-lo iterando pelas suas chaves com o [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var objectoMultidimensional = {'0':{campo: 'teste'},'1':{campo: 'valor qualquer'}, '2':{campo: 'teste'}}
var result3 = [], objecto;
Object.keys(objectoMultidimensional).forEach(function(key, index) {
   objecto = objectoMultidimensional[key]; 
   if (objecto.campo.indexOf(search) > -1) {
       result3.push(objecto)
   }
});

console.log(result3)
```

podes ainda usar o `Object.values` aliado ao `array.filter` se o browser o suportar (ou se estiveres a usar um shim):

```
var result4 = Object.values(objectoMultidimensional).filter(function(objecto) { 
    return objecto.campo.indexOf(search) > -1 
})

console.log(result4)
```

Como reparas, [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) retorna uma array com o os valores dentro do objecto providenciado, ao invés que `Object.keys()` só retorna as chaves do mesmo.

Para fazer o mesmo com o `search()` de que falei em cima:

```
var search = 'TESTE';
var regExp = new RegExp(search, 'i');
var resultado = ['olá', 'mundo', 'teste'].filter(function(text) { return text.search(regExp) > -1 });
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Testei aqui e não funcionou com meu array original, que esta nesse formato, como faço? : http://imgur.com/a/ROSwz

Comment: @LeoLetto editada para bater certo com o teu output :)

Comment: result4 funcionou perfeitamente pra mim, porém não tem um modo de simular o stripos? Pois a função só retorna dados quando eu digito o resultado exatamente como está no array, e como é pra ser um sistema de pesquisa, eu gostaria que fosse um pouco mais maleável com relação a isso

Comment: Opa já achei a solução aqui colocando toLowerCase() antes do indexOf, não sei se está certo mas aparentemente funcionou, Obrigadão pela ajuda @MoshMage

Comment: @LeoLetto falha minha: esqueci-me que o `strIpos` é case-insensitive; Nesse caso, usa `.search()` em vez de `indexOf` - mas terás que fazer uma expressao regular antes da palavra de procura; Editei a resposta para ter esse exemplo tambem

Comment: transformando tudo em letra minuscula já funcionou pra mim, seria necessária a mudança? kk é que já reestruturei tudo aqui pra tirar a interação com php

Comment: Nope, é só mais uma que podes usar :) *Edit: desde que nao faça diferença no teu output/input, o indexOf sem RegExp até é mais rápido)*